# Laravel Livewire summernote and others WYSIWYG editor are not working after re-render :(

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am a beginner in laravel livewire. When I open a model Summernote doesn't open with it. But if i try without livewire it works.

Not only that if I try normally without modal then it gets its value as null and if I do validation then summernote template is gone after showing error message.
here i showing my code!

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Backend\Portfolio;

use App\Models\Portfolio;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\Gd\Driver;

class PortfolioComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    #[Layout('livewire.layout.backend')]

    public $title;
    public $short_des;
    public $long_des;
    public $cover_image, $update_cover_image;
    public $portfolio;
    public $id;
    public $deleteModal;
    public $previewModel;
    public $status;
    public $edit;


    public function mount(){
        $this->portfolio  = Portfolio::latest()->get();
    }


    public function addPortfolio(){
        dd($this->long_des);
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'short_des' => 'required|max:100',
            'long_des' => 'required',
            'cover_image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048', // 1MB Ma
        ]);

        $portfolio = new Portfolio();
        $portfolio->title = $this->title;
        $portfolio->short_des = $this->short_des;
        $portfolio->long_des = $this->long_des;


        // Save Image
        if($this->cover_image){
            $manager = new ImageManager(new Driver());
            $img = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $this->cover_image->extension();
            $path ='/images/portfolio/'.$img; 
            $manager->read($this->cover_image)->resize(144, 217)->save(public_path('/images/portfolio/').$img);
            $portfolio->cover_image = $path;
        }
        $portfolio->status = 'active';
        $portfolio->save();
        $this->resetPage();
        session()->flash('success','Portfolio added successfully!');

    }//end method

    public function show($id){
        $this->id = $id;
        $portfolio = Portfolio::findOrFail($this->id);
        $this->title = $portfolio->title;
        $this->short_des = $portfolio->short_des;
       $this->long_des = $portfolio->long_des;
       $this->cover_image = $portfolio->cover_image;
       $this->status = $portfolio->status;
       $this->previewModel = true;
    }

        public function resetPage(){
        $this->reset(['title',
                    'short_des',
                    'long_des',
                    'cover_image',
                    'update_cover_image',
                    'deleteModal',
                    'id',
                    'previewModel',
                    'status',
                    'edit'
                ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.portfolio.portfolio-component');
    }
}
```

```
blade component:
```

```
     <form wire:submit.prevent>
                @csrf
                <div class="my-3">
                    <label for="title" class="label">Title:</label>
                    <input wire:model="title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" value="{{ old('title') }}" placeholder="Title">
                    @error('title') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                </div>
            
                <div class="my-3">
                    <label for="short_des" class="label">Short Description:</label>
                    <input wire:model="short_des" class="form-control @error('short_des') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" value="{{ old('short_des') }}" placeholder="Short Description">
                    @error('short_des') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                </div>
            
                <div class="my-3" >
                    <label for="long_des" class="label">Long Description:</label>
                    <textarea wire:model="long_des" id="summernote"  class="form-control summernote @error('long_des') is-invalid @enderror" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Details...">{{ old('long_des') }}</textarea>
                    @error('long_des') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                </div>
                
                <div class="my-3">
                    <label for="cover_image" class="cover_image">Cover Image:</label>
                    <input wire:model="cover_image" class="form-control  @error('cover_image') is-invalid @enderror" type="file">
                    @error('cover_image') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                </div>
                <button wire:click='addPortfolio' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3">Add Portfolio</button>
            </form>
```

```
<script> 
$('#summernote').summernote({
               height: 300,
               codemirror: {
                  mode: 'text/html',
                  htmlMode: true,
                  lineNumbers: true,
                  theme: 'monokai',
                  
               }
            });
</script>
```